# How can I catch a pound sign(#) from URL with multiple values in ASHX files

Tags: asp.net, httprequest, webrequest, httpcontext, ashx

This is my `ASHX` File where I am catching multiple parameters from request URL using `httpcontext`, and it is working properly but when I am including a Hash(#) value in Text parameter through the URL. It is not taking the value of FLOW which is another parameter(next to Text parameter).

So it is working for:

```
http://localhost:10326/ussd.ashx?user=MSL&pass=MSL663055&tid=65506&msisdn=8801520101525&text=***3333**&flow=begin&momt=mo
```

And it is not working for:

```
http://localhost:10326/ussd.ashx?user=MSL&pass=MSL663055&tid=65506&msisdn=8801520101525&text=***3333#**&flow=begin&momt=mo
```

My ASHX files:

```
public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
{
    HttpRequest httpRequest = context.Request;
    string user = httpRequest.QueryString["user"].ToString();
    string pass = httpRequest.QueryString["pass"].ToString();
    string tid = httpRequest.QueryString["tid"].ToString();
    string msisdn = httpRequest.QueryString["msisdn"].ToString();
    string text = httpRequest.QueryString["text"].ToString();
    flow = httpRequest.QueryString["flow"].ToString();
    HttpContext.Current.Session["user"] = user;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["pass"] = pass;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["tid"] = tid;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["msisdn"] = msisdn;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["text"] = text;
    HttpContext.Current.Session["flow"] = flow;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to URI encode your parameter values before they are added to the URL. This way the server will not get confused by unsafe characters such as '#' which has its own meaning when included as part of a URL. See [RFC 3986 Section 2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2).

See [Encode URL in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332872/encode-url-in-javascript) as an example of how to encode the sent data using JavaScript. Whatever is sending the data in the URL will need to do the encoding. There is not much you can do once the request has reached the server. Without knowing how your URL is being created, I can't offer much more.

In short: the problem is with your client code not your ASHX file.

Comment: correct, Functions for url encoding are .Net : `Httputility.UrlEncode()` , Javascript : `encodeURI()` or `encodeURIComponent()`

Comment: Section 3 even has a nice [ASCII graph](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc3986#section-3) that shows the URI parts, including the fragment